# how to deal with the pandas "id variables need to uniquely identify each row"?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe like:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'name1': ['A', 'A', 'C','B','C','A','D'],
    'name2': ['D', 'B', 'A','D','B','C','A'],
    'text': ['cars', 'cars', 'flower', 'tea','ball','phone','ice'],
    'time':['10/01','10/01','10/01','10/01','10/02','10/02','10/02'],
    'Flag1':[1,1,2,0,2,1,0],
    'Flag2':[0,0,1,0,0,2,1]})
```

expect:

```
pd.DataFrame({       
        'name': ['A', 'B', 'C','D','A','B','C'],
        'text': ['cars,flower','cars,tea', 'flower', 'cars,tea','phone,ice','ball','phone'],
        'time':['10/01','10/01','10/01','10/01','10/02','10/02','10/02'],
        'Flag':[1,0,2,0,1,0,2]})
```

I want to combine information according to "time". columns are merged by 'time';

'name': 'name1' and 'name2' are merged into 'name';

'words': on each day, words are merged once it shows up in the identical user's row;

'time': the date that the user shows up on that day;

'Flag': 'Flag1' and 'Flag2' are merge into 'Flag'. Each user has a unique
'Flag'('0','1','2') no matter what the date is.

But When I do:

```
pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=["name", "Flag"], i=["text", "time"], j="ref", 
suffix="\d*").reset_index().groupby(["name","time"],
as_index=False).agg({"text": ",".join, "Flag": "first"}).sort_values(["time", "name"])
```

I get:

```
id variables need to uniquely identify each row
```

How to deal with that?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: have added expect.

Comment: there should be a D for 10/02 right? also, C for 10/02 should be a combo of phone and ball

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this works for you. Try :

Reshape by getting the index in, to serve as unique identifier `i` :

```
m = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=["name", "Flag"], i="index", j="num")
```

Munge to get desired output, using groupby and some text manipulation :

```
(
    m.groupby(["name", "time"])
     .agg(Flag=("Flag", "first"), text=("text", lambda x: ",".join(set(x))))
    .reset_index()
    .sort_values("time")
)


    name    time    Flag    text
0   A       10/01   1   flower,cars
2   B       10/01   0   tea,cars
4   C       10/01   2   flower
6   D       10/01   0   tea,cars
1   A       10/02   1   phone,ice
3   B       10/02   0   ball
5   C       10/02   2   phone,ball
7   D       10/02   0   ice
```

Comment: Whe I do the 2nd step I get  : 
aggregate() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'

Comment: can you run it step wise, so you can find where the error is coming from? so take out everything after ``m.groupby(["name", "time"])`` and see if it works. if it works, add ``.agg(Flag=("Flag", "first"))`` only and see if you get a result, if it works, then add the text part into ``agg`` and see if it works. it is just a way to find where the error is. pandas version I am using is 1.1.1